# How to define a `std::set` sorting on another class data member?

Tags: c++, set, comparator

The code I tried, but doesn't work:

```
class A {
public:
    struct cmpr_t {
        bool operator() (int k1, int k2) {
            return mp[k1] < mp[k2];  // doesn't compile
        }
    };

    map<int, int> mp;  // storing key->value
    set<int, cmpr_t> ss;  // just keys, ordered by corresponding value in mp
};
```

I just want a `map` and also a `set`, the `map` stores data (key, value), and the `set` only contains the keys, and I want the `set` ordered by keys' corresponding values.

So how to define the set?

**UPDATE**

Compiler error:

```
In member function ‘bool SSet::cmpr_t::operator()(int, int)’:
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘SSet::mp’
     unordered_map<int, int> mp;  // k -> v
                             ^
error: from this location
             return mp[l] < mp[r];
                    ^
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘SSet::mp’
     unordered_map<int, int> mp;  // k -> v
                             ^
error: from this location
             return mp[l] < mp[r];
                            ^
```

Comment: `cmpr_t` can't access private members of class `A`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I don't think this is the problem, the compilers says that `cmpr_t` cannot access `mp`, because it's not a static data member.

Comment: A nested struct is unrelated to it's containing class, you can't access private members of the containing class. Also to make your question valid, post the compiler errors in your question verbatim, as usual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, error posted, and I've already made data member `public`, still can't compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Yes, it can access private members of the containing class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50d822553b14704a).

Comment: @Alcott You need to store e.g. a pointer to `A` in the comparator, so that it knows which `mp` to use.

Comment: @T.C., so how to solve my problem?

Comment: @T.C. If made static, OK. But I'm not so sure if this helps solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A 
{
    struct cmpr_t
    {
        A* a;
        explicit cmpr_t(A* a) : a(a) {}
        //                      ~~~^
        bool operator()(int k1, int k2) const
        {
            return a->mp[k1] < a->mp[k2];
            //     ~~^         ~~^
        }
    };
    std::map<int, int> mp;
    std::set<int, cmpr_t> ss;

public:         
    A() : ss(cmpr_t(this)) {}
    //       ~~~~~~~~~~~^ 
};
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to add `const` to `A* a` aka `const A * a`

Comment: @borisbn: Only if you don't want to modify the map, in which case you can't use `[]`.