# C++ set comparator using member fields

Tags: c++, set, comparator, functor

I would like to declare a `set<int>` as a member of my class, and I want to give it a custom comparator which will use the class instance fields inside of it.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() : my_set(fn_pt) {}
    std::vector<int> blocks;
    bool comp(int lhs, int rhs) {
      return blocks[lhs] < blocks[rhs];
    }
    bool(*fn_pt)(int,int)=comp;
    std::set<int, bool(*)(int,int)> my_set;
};
```

This gives an error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘MyClass::comp’ from type ‘bool (MyClass::)(int, int)’ 
to type ‘bool (*)(int, int)’
bool(*fn_pt)(int,int)=comp;
```

How can I get it to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As state in error `MyClass::comp` is `bool (MyClass::)(int, int)` not `bool (*)(int, int)`.

As you actually use `this`, making the method `static` is not a solution, you may instead do

```
std::set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> my_set;
```

and then

```
MyClass() : my_set([this](int lhs, int rhs) { return blocks[lhs] < blocks[rhs]; }) {}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just now found another way to do the same thing (similar idea but using a struct): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467980/how-to-define-a-stdset-sorting-on-another-class-data-member?rq=1

Comment: The value semantics of this class are broken with a setup like this.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Can you please elaborate, I don't understand. What alternative would you suggest? Thanks

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy: If you copy, move or assign an object of this class, the second object's comparison function will be using the `this` pointer of the first object, instead of itself. Then, any changes to the second object's vector will be ignored in the comparison. And worse, if the first object is destroyed, the second object will be left with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy: The alternative would be to make the class more robust. Jarod42's suggestions are fine, but you need to go further and manually define the copy/move constructors and the assignment operators such that each object's comparison function holds its own `this` pointer. Or alternatively, you can delete those functions if you don't want the object being copied or moved.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for your advice